# Docker Unknown File Permissions Windows 10

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I have an application running inside docker which programmatically creates files. Most of the time files are created properly and then deleted. Sometimes a file with unknown permission is created

```
drwxrwxrwx 0 root root 4096 Apr 17 21:41 ..
-????????? ? ?    ?       ?            ? __CG__NarwhalLayoutDomainEntitiesTheme.php
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8314 Apr 19 12:46 __CG__NarwhalLayoutDomainEntitiesTheme.php.5ad802fc34f6b0.60147712
```

When that happens though I can see the file in Windows Explorer when I try to delete it I get this error:

```
"You need permission to perform this action"
"You require permission from the computer's administrator to make changes to this file"
```

I even tried as administrator but it still won't work and when I try to delete the file from inside the container shell. I get this error:

rm: cannot remove '__CG__NarwhalLayoutDomainEntitiesTheme.php': No such file or directory

This problem goes away when I restart the docker but I don't want to restart docker every few minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is an ongoing problem with docker for windows. I found a temporary solution here https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/525

I fixed the problem by simply pointing my doctrine proxies to a folder inside the container such as /tmp and is not mounted.